# TypeError: val.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I get this error when making a query in nodejs:

```
[2017-08-19 19:06:55.946] [ERROR] error - TypeError: val.slice is not a function
    at escapeString (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:183:23)
    at Object.escape (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:53:21)
    at Connection.escape (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:270:20)
```

The query:

```
pool.query('INSERT INTO trades SET user = ' + pool.escape(row[i].csteamid) + ', tid = ' + pool.escape(makeTID) + ', status = ' + pool.escape('PendingAccept') + ', items = ' + pool.escape(Items.join('/')) + ', action = ' + pool.escape('expired') + ', code = ' + pool.escape(cod));
```

How can I fix this issue? I'm not using "val" or the slice function in the query.

Comment: Had the same issue, it turned out that I was passing a function rather than a string.  The clarity of the error message could be improved a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an indication that you have a `pool.escape` call with an argument that is not a string. `slice` is used in the implementation of that `escape` method.

There are three candidate calls that could be responsible for this error:

```
pool.escape(row[i].csteamid) 
pool.escape(makeTID) 
pool.escape(cod)
```

Debug your code to see whether one of these is (sometimes) not a string (like `null`, `undefined` or an object, ....)

You can force the argument to be a string like this, although that will almost certainly not give the desired result:

```
pool.escape(row[i].csteamid + '') 
pool.escape(makeTID + '') 
pool.escape(cod + '')
```

Better is to test the data type before you create this SQL string, with this:

```
if (typeof row[i].csteamid !== 'string') throw `row[${i}].csteamid is not a string, but ${typeof row[i].csteamid}`;
if (typeof makeTID !== 'string') throw `makeTID is not a string, but ${typeof makeTID}`;
if (typeof cod !== 'string') throw `cod is not a string, but ${typeof cod}`;
```

Comment: You were right! makeTID was a function that returns a string. So I made a variable called makeTID that ran the function before the query. Works like a charm.

edit: probably also works to run the function inside pool.escape().